# how does foo({1,2}) work for "void foo(pair<int,int>)"

Tags: c++11

`std::pair` has no constructor which take initializer list as argument, but how does the following code compile?

```
void foo(std::pair<int,int> pr)
{
}

void foo2(std::tuple<int,int,int> t)
{
}

void bar()
{
    foo({1,2});                               // compile OK
    foo(std::pair<int,int>{1,2});             // compile OK
    foo2(std::tuple<int,int,int>{1,2,3});     // compile OK
    foo2({1,2,3});     // compile error
}
```

I am using clang3.7.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uniform initialization isn't about initializer lists. A braced-init-list (the technical term for `{}` when used to initialize an object) can call *any* constructor (though it can be restricted to non-explicit constructors only, depending on how you use it). It prefers `initializer_list` constructors, but it will call any constructor that matches its argument list.

So it calls the `pair` constructor that takes two parameters of the appropriate type.

`foo2` is a compile error for the reason I alluded to above. `pair`'s constructor that takes two values is not explicit, but the equivalent constructor for `tuple` is explicit. Therefore, you need to use the type's name explicitly to call the constructor:

```
foo2(std::tuple<int, int, int>{1,2,3});
```

Note that in C++17, this `tuple` constructor will be made non-explicit, if the types in the type-list can be converted from the given types non-explicitly. So your original statement should work under a C++17 implementation.

Comment: "Uniform initialization isn't about initializer lists." I always confuse about {},Thanks a lot for clarifcation!